# webpack obfuscate filenames before import

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle a react app that is being deployed in multiple locations, for multiple customers. It's important that each build of the app works for all customers. In other words, there is one build process.

These customers (can) have custom translation texts. These are stored in the repo in JSON files.

Let's say:

```
client_translations/en.ford.json
client_translations/en.tesla.json
client_translations/de.porsche.json
```

When a user logs in, the app then receives the customerId and thus knows which translation file to load (using `import`).

```js
const getClientTranslations = async (customerId: string, language: string) => {
  try {
    const clientTranslations = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "client_translation-[index]" */
    /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      `client_translations/${language}.${customerId}.json`
    )
    return clientTranslations ?? {}
  }
}
```

So, what webpack does is it makes nice chunks like this `client_translation-5318-bundle.js`, and the app determines which one of these to inject into the page. So far so good.

Now what follows is somewhere within the main bundle there is a mapping between the filename, which includes the name of the customer, and the `client_translation-XX-bundle.js` file. Such that webpack can find the file when I do the import. But this also means that our customer, say 'ford', can dig through the main bundle and find out that our other customers are 'tesla' and 'porsche', by looking at these file names.

This is apparently a problem for my client so what I would like to do is, import the json with a hashed name:

```
  `client_translations/${language}.${md5Hash(customerId)}.json`
```

so the import would resolve to `client_translations/en.80ca06abfa1a5104af9a770f485dad07.js`. *However* in the repo, I would like to keep the filename unhashed, because obviously it's super annoying for developers to find things when it's all hashed.

So can we do this hashing or any other type of obfuscation *at build time* ?

ps. I know MD5 is not secure, that's kind of besides the point. Another type of (fast) hashing is also fine by me, but this question is not about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No amount or type of hashing is going to solve this problem for you. But having said that, you can obfuscate reference to your translations files completely from the main bundle code so that your client cannot peek into other available translations unless they know the customer Id.

To achieve this, you can treat your translations as [plain assets](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead of importing them using dynamic `import()` expression. The key thing is to use `fetch()` API instead as follows:

```js
function getClientTranslations<T>(customerId: string, language: string): Promise<T> {

  // Sample hashing. But not useful as hashing algorithm will be seen by the client.
  const hashed = btoa(customerId);

  const translations = fetch(`/public/client_translations/${language}.${hashed}.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(() => ({}));

  return translations;
}
```

By using `fetch` instead of `import()`, Webpack will not see these files and add them to the bundle. Now second step will be using the **asset module** as shown below:

```js
import { btoa } from 'node:buffer';
import path from 'node:path';

const config = {
  mode: 'production',

  // Entry point and output
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: process.cwd() + '/dist',
    filename: 'output.js',
    assetModuleFilename(pathData, _assetInfo) {
      const { filename } = pathData;

      // For each, en.ford.json, we get ['en', 'ford', 'json']
      const [lang, customerId, ext] = path.basename(filename).split('.');

      // We want to output the file as dist/translations/lang.{hashedId}.json
      // Use base64 as a dummy hashing function
      const hash = btoa(customerId);

      return `translations/${lang}.${hash}.${ext}`;
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',

        // Added additional condition so that other imported
        // JSON files are not included. Change it accordingly.
        include: /client_translations/
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default config;
```

The important configuration here is `assetModuleFilename` in the `output` configuration and use of `asset/resource` for handling your JSON files.

Finally, keep in mind that you still need to tell Webpack to pick up the asset files. For that, we will use [side-effect `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only). Side effect import + `asset/resource` will ensure that your main bundle doesn't contain any kind of reference to the translation files. Your entry point will look something like this:

```js
import './client_translations/en.ford.json';
import './client_translations/en.tesla.json';

async function main() {
  await getClientTranslations('ford', 'en');
}

main();
```

Alternately, you can also use a 3rd-party plugin to simply copy these files are they are using [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/). The overall idea remains the same; just that with copy plugin, you won't need to import these assets manually in the bundle code. I would recommend it if you have 100s of files and don't want to manually write code to import all of it. Irrespective of the technique, end result will be same.

The challenge with any kind of hashing in this case is that you will have to map the `customerId` on client-side (bundled code) with the same hashing algorithm. So, it doesn't matter. As long as client knows other customers Ids, with or without hash, the security implication is same. The only measure here is obfuscation to some extent by removing the references to the translation files. And, also note that, this is fragile from caching perspective. You should use proper hashing keys which are based on Hash of the content of the file.

In order to have full 100% security, you can do one of the two things:

1. Let the translations be returned by the server via API. It can add proper authorization. You can continue to use local translation files in dev mode but in production, replace the fetch URL with proper API URL. Your build/deployment script can then upload these files to protected cloud storage and API can simply pull from that at runtime.
2. Keep the hashing algorithm **secret** and use salt. And, somehow let the API return this hashed value in the initial user info call when the app loads, so that your client code can simply use this hashed value instead of calculating it on front-end.

Comment: Note: base64 is not a hashing algorithm and can be decoded back to its original content.

Comment: @Marc Yes, that is true. It is just added for illustration purpose in the example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up going with the WebpackCopyPlugin approach. Also thanks for the caveats about this being 'fake' security. I agree, but as you might understand, I have clients' wishes to comply to, and a bit of obfuscation is enough to do that. You are absolutely right that an API would be a more robust solution.